Data Plotly plugin in QGIS 3.10 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
No module named pandas error while installing the Data Plotly plugin. I installed pandas by running "conda install pandas" in the terminal but problem persists.
QGIS version: 3.10
Ubuntu: 20.04 LTS


It seems like you have multiple python installations. Make sure, that you install your desired library into the correct python path.

You can't use conda to install python packages for use with the system python that QGIS is using.  Just pip install your required packages. If you really want to use conda to install packages to use with QGIS, you need to create a conda env that includes a conda packaged QGIS.
